# Make a call in Lwuit using textfield

Tags: java-me, lwuit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doing a phone call in LWUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921523/doing-a-phone-call-in-lwuit)

I have created text field with phone number.How do i make a call when call button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following one for make a call from your application,

```
String phoneNo = textfield.getText();
Display.getInstance().execute("tel:" + phoneNo );
```

(Or)

If your TextField in MIDlet class, you can use like this.

```
String phoneNo = textfield.getText();
platformRequest("tel:" + phoneNo );
```

Both are works fine.

Comment: thanks bharath.I have another one doubt.how to configure call button to that textfield.

Comment: @user1166836 that isn't possible